# What is the social rule regarding eye-contact in Poland?

Tags: poland, social-norms

Do Polish people in Eastern (historic Russian) Poland avoid eye contact while talking to brown people, or, is it a social norm in Poland?

If it is a social norm, is this also prevalent in Western (historic German) Poland?

I am asking as I have been living here for a while now. Through lengthy experimentation, I came to the conclusion that this is about xenophobia but wondered if anyone else's experience match so I can be 100% sure.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism_in_Europe#Poland): `Poland tops the list of countries with most attacks on Indian students with 9 of 21 incidents`, Indians are browns (I am brown as well, mocha to be exact lol, not Indian though). Reading here and there, it seems that Poland's level of xenophobia is considered very high.

Comment: How could there be a definite answer?? What makes you assume there even _could_ be a law or rule that binds all polish people to behave the same way?

Comment: @aganju Asker isn't asking about a law. Asker is asking about a 'social rule' or 'social norm'. Are you saying you don't accept that such things exist?

Comment: Different cultures have different standards about eye contact (often varying between strangers and friends/relatives), but it's a leap to assume it's because of skin colour.

Comment: @StuartF,  *it's a leap to assume it's because of skin color.* --- I have been living here for a while now. Through lengthy experimentation, I came to the conclusion that this is about xenophobia. I am here to hear this from another person if his experience matches so I can be 100% sure. Coz, no Polish person would verbally admit that.

Comment: But one other person's experience wouldn't be a "definite answer" as to whether it is a general social norm, would it?

Comment: @NateEldredge, *one other person's experience wouldn't be a "definite answer" as to whether it is a general social norm, would it?* --- depends on how the answer is formulated.

Comment: Are your sure it is about your skin colour and not about "(historic Russian) Poland" and "(historic German) Poland"?